# Flutter FCM doesn't trigger onBackgroundMessage

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've followed all the steps to implement FCM in my app and in iOS weverything works fine but on Android when the app is on background (and suppose on terminated too) I receive notification in the system tray and when I tap the app start and I receive onResume in the following format:

> google.sent_time: number, click_action:
> FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.original_priority: high,
> collapse_key: app_name_here, google.delivered_priority: high,
> from: number, google.message_id:
> 0:1597765388628367%42e897xc324e35dc4e42e8974e, google.ttl: number

... and it seems there are no data nor notification so I have no idea how to get the message data.

The method I use onBackground is a top level func:

```
Future<dynamic> onBackgroundMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  debugPrint('On background message $message');
  print('On background message $message');
  stderr.writeln('stderr.writeln $message');
  return Future<void>.value();
}
```

I have to mention I don't receive the print output but I DO receive the notification in the system tray, so I'm not sure if this function triggers at all.
Anyone with ideas how to debug this?
Question edited, some details added!